# How to restarting server from an IIS process running on Azure?

Tags: c#, iis, azure, iis-7

We're running a WCF service on Azure and we want to be able to restart the machine from code.

I've attempted the following methods:

**Method 1 - Using Process.Start("shutdown.exe")**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.start

Problem with this method - IIS 7 has security by the application pool, and manually changing permissions/etc on Azure resets and can't be trusted.

I've attempted using `icacls` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) to give IIS permission to run `shutdown.exe` but unfortunately it seems that it doesn't work on files inside the `system32` folder.

**Method 2 - Calling RoleEnvironment.RequestRecycle**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.requestrecycle.aspx

We've used this function, it works well - however we require a full server restart and not just a role instance recycle.

**Method 3 - Using Azure's REST API**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg441298.aspx

This so far looks the most promising method of achieving this, I was able to get this to work from my dev machine by generating a certificate, uploading it as a management certificate on the Azure portal, however, for the life of me I couldn't get the **management** certificate from the Azure instance itself.

---

So - If anyone can think of a way to make method 1 or 3 work is great, or if you can think of another option - it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Method 3 (Using Azure's Management Libraries), and I used the base64 encoded management certificate inside the Publish settings file (which can be downloaded here https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx).

Inside there was the base64 string of the management certificate attached to my subscription.

Not the prettiest solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Azure Powershell cmdlets(http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/).

You can then run `Restart-AzureVM`(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495199.aspx) + many other other management commands

Comment: This tutorial should have all you need:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx